How do I add roles from a slash command with a python discord bot?
I am completely new to python, and I'm trying to code a discord bot for my server. I am trying to add a role to the message author, which I will later switch to a specifed person.
import discord
from discord import app_commands, message, guild, context_managers, interactions, member, role
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is up and ready!")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


@bot.tree.command(name="hello")
async def hello(interaction: guild.Member.roles):
    __member__ = message.Member
    __Guild__ = discord.Guild
    role = discord.utils.get(message.Guild.roles, id="1235347026967789618")

    await interaction.member.add_roles(role)




bot.run("token")

This booted properly, and gave both messages expected "Bot is up and ready!" and "Synced 1 command(s)"
When I used the command on my test server, I got the error message:
[2024-05-01 20:18:35] [ERROR   ] discord.app_commands.tree: Ignoring exception in command 'hello' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\myName\PycharmProjects\discordBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 828, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\myName\PycharmProjects\discordBot\main.py", line 23, in hello
    role = discord.utils.get(message.Guild.roles, id="1235347026967789618")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\myName\PycharmProjects\discordBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 595, in get
    else _get(iterable, **attrs)  # type: ignore
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\myName\PycharmProjects\discordBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 492, in _get
    return next((elem for elem in iterable if pred(elem) == v), None)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\myName\PycharmProjects\discordBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)   File "C:\Users\myName\PycharmProjects\discordBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 853, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\myName\PycharmProjects\discordBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 842, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'hello' raised an exception: TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable


Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Your code is full of errors from start to end. Like why is the interaction object is a role objects and what does __member__ and __Guild__ do. You are not even getting message object from the context. I just don't know where to start fixing.
